# Drop Index , then Insert Statement after that Create back Index, does not work in Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSSEL_TBL_TEST AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
  TBL varchar2(50):= 'ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2';
  tblNm varchar2(50);

CURSOR tableIndexList IS 
(select ES_INDEX_NM,ES_TBL_NM,ES_CRT_INDEX_STMT,ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT FROM ESSP.ESSINDEXCONF WHERE ES_TBL_NM = TBL);

BEGIN
  FOR drpInd in tableIndexList LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT';
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  execute immediate ('insert into ESSPREP.' ||UPPER(TBL)|| ' select * from ESSP.' ||UPPER(TBL)|| '@ESSPREPLINKESSP');

  FOR drpInd in tableIndexList Loop
    execute immediate 'drpInd.ES_CRT_INDEX_STMT';
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
END;
```

above is my procedure to drop index before insert statement, after that create back the index.But it not work,anyone can help ?

Comment: Hi @GteckHan, It will be really help full if you can show us what is the data present in TableA after you are inserting from db link. My doubt is something is not getting inserted properly. Also if you can tell us the exact error that will help.

Comment: Hi @Ankit Mongia..done edit the procedure.

Comment: i hit SQL Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at "ESSP.INSSEL_TBL_TEST", line 12
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"

Comment: I suspect problem is in insert statement when you are using dblink.

Comment: you want see the field contain's value ?
Create UNIQUE index IND_ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 ON ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 (CW_S_BNK,CW_S_BR,ES_BRIC,ES_STMT_ID)

Comment: Can you share the results 3 queries. 1.) The first cursor query you are using. 2.) Insert the data manually by hard coding the table name. 3.) Again share the result of the cursor query.

Comment: There is no need to `commit` DDL statements in Oracle

Comment: Don't put variable names in single quotes. `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT';` should be `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT;`

Comment: but the error shown from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT';

Comment: INSERT INTO ESSINDEXCONF (ES_INDEX_NM,ES_TBL_NM,ES_CRT_INDEX_STMT,ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT) VALUES ('IND_ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2','ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2','Create UNIQUE index IND_ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 ON ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 (CW_S_BNK,CW_S_BR,ES_BRIC,ES_STMT_ID)','DROP INDEX IND_ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2');

Comment: Try running that command on its own: `Create UNIQUE index IND_ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 ON ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2 (CW_S_BNK,CW_S_BR,ES_BRIC,ES_STMT_ID)`

Comment: Also, add some debug statements to see what value is being retrieved before it calls execute immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Line

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT';
```

is wrong. You're trying to use value from cursor but as a fact you're using string literal. To fix this error just remove quotes:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT;
```

Also, as @XING said, commit is superfluous here.

Answer (score -1):

Your `syntax` is not correct. See below:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSSEL_TBL_TEST 
AS

  TBL varchar2(50):= 'ESSCSHSTMTBPTEST2';
  tblNm varchar2(50);

CURSOR tableIndexList IS 
(select ES_INDEX_NM,ES_TBL_NM,ES_CRT_INDEX_STMT,ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT FROM ESSP.ESSINDEXCONF WHERE ES_TBL_NM = TBL);

BEGIN

  FOR drpInd in tableIndexList LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE drpInd.ES_DROP_INDEX_STMT;
    --COMMIT;-- DROP is a DDL hence no need for COMMIT
  END LOOP;

  execute immediate 'insert into ESSPREP.' ||UPPER(TBL)|| ' select * from ESSP.' ||UPPER(TBL)|| '@ESSPREPLINKESSP';

  FOR drpInd in tableIndexList Loop
    execute immediate drpInd.ES_CRT_INDEX_STMT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: If the syntax is not correct, point out what that syntax error is.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I posted the whole code with inline comments and removing unnecessary stuffs. Did you had time to go through it before posting your comments which is not contributing more to my answer rather its more spamming. I don't expect you to order me to point out what i need to do and i should not do. If you think you can answer better, you can post your valuable answer.